# Sharing classes between iOS and watchOS

Tags: ios, swift, watchos, watchos-4

I currently have an iOS app. Based on the user location it uses a class or another. How am I doing this for my iOS app? I have a `protocol`:

```
protocol ParseProtocol {

    var urlToParse: URL? { get }
    var parsedXMLData: [MyData] { get }

    func parseFeed()

    init()
}
```

And then on the `ViewController` when I detect the city the user is in,  `parser` function is called and generates a class depending on a `String` in which the user is in:

```
func parser(for city: String) -> ParseProtocol? {

        let bundlePath     = Bundle.main.bundlePath
        let bundleFullName = bundlePath.components(separatedBy: "/").last
        let bundleName     = bundleFullName?.components(separatedBy: ".").first
        let combinedName   = bundleName! + "." + cityIn + "Parser"
        let Class          = NSClassFromString(combinedName) as? ParseProtocol.Type

        print("CITY: \(city)  \(combinedName)")

        return Class?.init()
    }
```

Now, I'm developing a watchOS complication and I'd like to use the same classes as before for watchOS and iOS as they are the same. My problem comes here, as they are different bundles the `combinedName` differ:

- watchOS `combinedName` is MyApp-watchOS Extension.LondonParser
- iOS `combinedName` is MyApp.LondonParser

I am pretty stuck here and don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: what about adding `LondonParser` & whichever the other similar classes are to the  WatchKit Extension target? One class can be in multiple targets

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use `NSClassFromString` based on the current bundle, you can do it like that:

```
let targetName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary![kCFBundleNameKey as String] as! String
let Class = NSClassFromString("\(targetName).\(className)") as? ParseProtocol.Type
```

Of course the target name will be different for every target, but this is no problem, if you added the desired class to the target. From the extension target, you cannot access classes only added to the host app target.

For clarification: Your application consists of one or more products (targets). Each target has three names:

1. The display name: The Name displayed under the app icon on the home screen
2. The bundle identifier: The (globally) unique identifier of the target
3. The target name: The name used for identification of the target during compile time

The third name is the one used for class creation with `NSClassFromString`. Please also note, that the target name MUST not contain spaces like in `"MyApp-watchOS Extension"`. The compiler then cannot find the class.

Comment: My question is if it's possible to access a class that is in the project. It's currently added to both targets (iOS + watchOS extension) but I cannot do it. I'd like to not to have duplicate classes for my iOS app and then for my watchOS app.

Comment: What is the problem with adding the same class to multiple targets? Anyway, there are no "project classes". The project is just a container for the targets. Maybe you can import your host app target into your watch extension with `import MyApp`. But I am pretty sure that this will raise more problems than it will solve.